# Was bedeutet das Wort Vorzeigetier?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Kann mir jemand bitte erklären, was das Wort ,,Vorzeigetier’’ bedeutet.

Das Wort habe ich in einem [Buch](https://books.google.de/books?id=DEc1DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT3&ots=tphzWj5ux5&dq=Vorzeigetier&hl=de&pg=PT3#v=onepage&q=Vorzeigetier&f=false) gelesen. Es heißt dort „...weil es keinen besseren Beleg für unseren wunderbaren Aufstieg vom Staub zum Vorzeigetier gibt als die Potenzierung des Wissens durch die Wissenschaft. Vor zwei Millionen Jahren waren wir Affenmenschen. Nun sind wir Raumfahrer.“

Vielen Dank für all die Antworten. :)

Comment: Hallo, und Willkommen auf german.se! Hast du noch ein bisschen mehr Kontext? Das würde helfen, die Frage zu beantworten. Ohne jeden Kontext müsste ein Vorzeigetier ein Tier sein, das zum zum Vorzeigen verwendet wird, oder ein Tier, das vorgezeigt wird.

Comment: Ein besonders gepflegtes oder besonders zahmes Tier, das man Fremden gefahrlos zeigen kann.

Comment: Scheint mir so eine spontane Wortkomposition von irgendjemandem zu sein, der ein besonders vorzeigbares Tier meint. Habe ich jedenfalls noch nie gehört.

Comment: Sicher, dass es kein Vorzeitgetier ist? ;)

Comment: Ja, ich habe nochmal nachgeguckt. Es ist nicht Vorzeitgetier, wobei ich dieses Wort auch nicht kenne. Also was bedeutet denn Vorzeitgetier :D

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorzeige_

Comment: Und für die anderen Danke erstmal für die Antworten. Ich habe die Frage bearbeitet.

Comment: @Carsten S das habe ich schon gelesen. Verstehe aber immer noch nicht was im Text mit Vorzeigetier gemeint ist :D

Comment: In dem zitierten Satz ist mit "Vorzeigetier" der Mensch oder die Menschheit gemeint. Da diese Seite inzwischen oberster Treffer bei Google ist, ist das Wort so gut wie unbekannt, die Zusammensetzung von "Vorzeige" und "Tier" und bedeutet, was auch immer der Autor damit sagen will. Bei diesem Buch macht schon die Einleitung einen konfusen Eindruck.

Comment: Vorzeigetier bedeutet so viel wie: das Tier, das das beste Beispiel für etwas ist. Siehe z.B. hier: https://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/frauenfeld-munchwilen/der-biber-vorzeigetier-und-schadenstifter-ld.797983

Answer (score 7):

Es scheint sich um eine Wortschöpfung des Autors zu handeln.

Die Verbindung eines Begriffs mit "Vorzeige-" wird benutzt, um Exemplare dieses Begriffs zu bezeichnen, die besonders "vorzeigbar" sind, also besonders beispielhaft oder besonders gut in irgendeinem Sinn. Siehe auch den Eintrag im Duden: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorzeige_

> Vorzeigeschüler
> Vorzeigeprojekt
> Vorzeigeexemplar

Hier wird der Mensch als "Vorzeigetier" bezeichnet, also als eine besonders vorzeigbare, besonders renommierte Art von Tier.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort "Vorzeige" wird oft anderen Substantiven vorangestellt, etwa wie bei

- Vorzeigebeispiel
- Vorzeigeschüler (vgl. das Buch "Der Vorzeigeschüler" von Annerose Schlesinger)

Es ist damit gemeint, dass etwas einem *Idealbild* entspricht.

Ob der Mensch (der biologisch  dem Tierreich angehört) das **Idealbild eines Tieres** ist, sei dahingestellt. Vielleicht will de Autor auf das außergewöhnliche Entwicklungspotenzial des Menschen im Vergleich zu anderer Tierarten hinweisen.

Comment: Vorzeigebeispiel ist aber doppelt gemoppelt.

Comment: @userunknown Doppelt gemoppelt vielleicht nicht, aber besonders gutes Deutsch auch nicht. Das Wort ist dennoch im [Gebrauch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vorzeigebeispiel).

Comment: Was ist ein Beispiel denn sonst, wenn nicht ein Exemplar, das man vorzeigt?

Comment: @userunknown Das Vorzeigebeispiel ist ein besonders gutes Beispiel. "Paradebeispiel" ist eine andere Variante. Vgl.dwds  [hier](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vorzeigebeispiel) und [hier](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Paradebeispiel).

Comment: Da eine Parade auch ein Akt des Vorzeigens ist, trifft die Feststellung, dass es doppelt gemoppelt ist, dafür ebenfalls zu. Dass beides in Gebrauch ist, bestreite ich nicht. Die Verdopplung dient der Unterstreichung. Ich mache lediglich darauf aufmerksam, dass man "Beispiel" auch ohne "Vorzeige~" verwenden kann, nämlich wenn man es  nicht besonders betonen möchte, also im Normalfall. Als Beispieltier mag hier die Maus gelten, sicher ein gutes Beispiel, aber kein Paradebeispiel.

Answer (score 1):

In diesem Kontext wird Vorzeigetier als Antonym zu Staub benutzt, wobei Staub hier als extremste Vorstufe von Materie benutzt wird (vgl. Sternenstaub), noch vor Einzellern als einer ersten Stufe von Leben. Auf dieser Skala "Staub <----> Vorzeigetier" befindet sich der Mensch eben am weitesten "rechts". Das heißt, er hat sich nicht nur von etwas Staub über einzelliges Leben zu einem Tier, also komplexen Leben entwickelt. Nein, er ist der Prototyp von einem hoch-/gut-/schön-entwickelten Tier geworden, u.a. weil er die Raumfahrt beherrscht. Einem Tier, dass man als "gutes" Beispiel vorzeigen würde, wenn eine außerirdische Lebensform ein Buch über den Planeten Erde schreiben würde.

Comment: Bist du dir sicher, dass dein letzter Absatz den Grundtenor des Originaltextes richtig wiedergibt? Ich denke, da ist etwas zu viel deiner eigenen Meinung eingeflossen.

Comment: Da war ich wohl etwas zu sehr im Flow.

Answer (score 1):

Ein *Vorzeige-Ding* ist ein *Ding* das man *vorzeigen* kann weil es so außergewöhnlich gut/schön/effizient usw. ist.

Man hat eine größere Menge verschiedener Dinge, und wenn jemand fragt, wie denn diese Dinge beschaffen sind, und man den Fragestellen davon überzeugen möchte, dass sie besonders positive Eigenschaften haben, dann wählt man aus diesen Dingen ein Exemplar aus, dass der Idealvorstellung möglichst nahe kommt, und *zeigt* dieses Ding *vor.* Dadurch wird das ausgewählte Sonder-Exemplar zum *Vorzeige-Ding.*

**Beispiel:**

Der Besitzer einer Apfel-Plantage möchte seine Äpfel verkaufen und möchte ein Werbe-Video drehen, um den Verkauf anzukurbeln. In dem Video sollen natürlich Äpfel von dieser Plantage zu sehen sein. Dazu nimmt der Apfel-Bauer aber nicht irgendwelche Äpfel, und schon gar nicht die Äpfel, die für die Saftpresse bestimmt sind, sondern er wählt ganz besonders große und regelmäßig geformte aus, die auch ganz genau die gewünschte Farbe haben. Er wählt also Äpfel aus, die man auch in einem Werbevideo vorzeigen kann. Das sind dann *Vorzeigeäpfel.*

---

Ein *Vorzeige-Ding* kann aber auch das einzige Ding einer bestimmten Kategorie sein, um damit den Nachweis zu erbringen, dass man überhaupt etwas aus dieser Kategorie besitzt.

**Beispiel:**

Es gibt Männer, denen die Kariere wichtiger als ihr Familienleben ist. Um bestimmte Positionen besetzen zu können, wird es aber gern gesehen, wenn man verheiratet ist oder wenigstens in einer festen Beziehung lebt. Manche Kariere-Männer heiraten daher Frauen zum alleinigen Zweck, sie bei Empfängen, Feiern usw. vorzeigen zu können. Diese Frauen nennt man *Vorzeigefrauen.*
Ähnliches gilt für *Vorzeigefreundinnen* schwuler Männer, die sich nicht outen möchten.

---

Der Begriff *»Vorzeigetier«* gehört im vorliegenden Kontext aber zur ersten Definition, wobei hier mit *»Tier«* eigentlich *»Tierart«* oder *»Gattung«* gemeint ist (pars pro toto).

Den Menschen (als Gattung und Tierart) kann man vorzeigen, wenn es darum geht, zu beweisen, zu welchen Leistungen die Evolution fähig ist. Alles Leben hat sich aus Staub entwickelt (hier wird *»Staub«* durchaus im biblischen Sinne verwendet: Prediger 3:20 *»... es ist alles von Staub gemacht und wird wieder zu Staub.«*), und daraus sind viele verschiedene Tierarten und Gattungen entstanden. Und unter diesem vielen Arten und Gattungen kann man die Gattung *»Mensch«* vorzeigen, denn diese Gattung hat es immerhin geschafft in den Weltraum zu reisen. Die Gattung *»Mensch«* ist also eine *Vorzeige-Gattung,* oder eben ein *Vorzeige-Tier.*

Comment: Eine "Vorzeigefrau ist nicht unbedingt eine Frau, die ein Mann alleine zum Zweck des "Vorzeigens" geheiratet hat. Ja, er mag sich in  ihrem Glanz sonnen, aber man sollte das nicht auf ein singuäres Motiv verengen.  Vgl. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorzeigefrau